# Flexbox 2x2 grid - input inside overflows the flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to have a flexbox 2x2 grid that contain a random number of elements (odd or even). I've achieved to create this flexbox without any problems.

When I added my content: input fields with width 100% I noticed that those are bigger then their flex container which seems odd. In the example this is easy to spot on the last red box.

How can I make the input fields be 100% of the flex container?

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}
.grid-item {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background: #F90;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F00;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <input type="text" value="email">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <input type="text" value="email">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <input type="text" value="email">
  </div>

</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x3pyenkL/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> The box-sizing property is used to alter the default CSS box model used to calculate width and height of the elements.

Set `box-sizing: border-box` for `<input>` elements.

```
input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Or better to add for all elements of your page for consistency.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}
.grid-item {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background: #F90;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F00;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <input type="text" value="email">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <input type="text" value="email">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <input type="text" value="email">
  </div>

</div>
```